# A test for the convergence of a sequence in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$. Let $Y=\{\frac{1}{n}\;\vert\; n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and give $Y$ the subspace topology as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges to $x\in X$ if and only if the function $f\colon Y\to X,\quad \frac{1}{j}\mapsto a_j,\;0\mapsto x$ is continuous.

Here is my short attempt:

Suppose $a_1,a_2,\dots$ converges to $\in X$. Let $U\subseteq X$ be open. If $x\in U$, then there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a_n\in U$ for all $n\geq N$, so $f^{-1}(U)=\{\frac{1}{N},\frac{1}{N+1},\dots\}=Y\cap (-1,\frac{1}{N-1})$ is open in $Y$.

I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct in the above. Could there be $a_n\in U$ with $n<N$? In that case, what I've written for $f^{-1}(U)$ is incorrect. I also don't know how to proceed in the case $x\not\in U$. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your concern, yest there could be $a_n \in U$ with $n < N$. As a simple example, assume that $U$ contained the entire sequence. Then $N = 7$ satisfies your criterion for $N$, but $a_1, \dots, a_6$ are still in $U$.

Now, here's an approach to solving this:
Assume that $a_n \to x$, and let $U \subset X$ be open. First, if $x \in U$, then infinitely many $a_i$'s are in $U$. Therefore, $f^{-1}(U)$ contains all but a finite number of the $\frac1j$'s. Can you now show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open using this fact? Next, if $x \not\in U$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ contains only a finite number of the $\frac1j$'s. Again, you should be able to prove it is open from here.

Note that this only proves the forward direction of the statement; you still need to prove the converse.